# Finding latitude and longitude for pixel values

Tags: geotiff-tiff, rasterio

```
import rasterio as rio
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = rio.open('/Users/rchaughule/Desktop/S_197901_concentration_v3.0.tif') 
val = dataset.read() 
no_data=dataset.nodata
data = [(dataset.xy(x,y)[0],dataset.xy(x,y)[1],val[x,y]) for x,y in np.ndindex(val.shape) if val[x,y] != no_data]
lon = [i[0] for i in data]
lat = [i[1] for i in data()]
d = [i[2] for i in data()]
res = pd.DataFrame({"long":lon,'lat':lat,"data":d})
res.head()
```

I'm trying to write a code to find pixel coordinates in a geotiff. But it keeps showing me the error :

```
"too many values to unpack (expected 2)" at 
data = [(dataset.xy(x,y)[0],dataset.xy(x,y)[1],val[x,y]) for x,y in np.ndindex(val.shape) if val[x,y] != no_data]
```

Where is the error.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following which:

- only reads the data into memory once and as required as it uses `dataset.sample()` instead of `dataset.read()` and generators instead of list comprehension
- uses `itertools.tee` to avoid running `dataset.xy` twice

```py
from itertools import tee
import rasterio as rio
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


with rio.open('input.tif') as dataset:
    shape = dataset.shape
    nodata = dataset.nodata

    xy1, xy2 = tee(dataset.xy(x, y) for x, y in np.ndindex(shape))  # save re-running dataset.xy
    data = ((x, y, z[0]) for (x, y), z in zip(xy1, dataset.sample(xy2)) if z[0] != nodata)
    res = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["lon", "lat", "data"])
    print(res.head())
```